# convert data to xml using sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert my data to xml string using a sql query. I tried below code (with RAW, AUTO, PATH) but the output format is different. How to get the required format?

```
DECLARE @ValueVM TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Text VARCHAR(MAX),
    IsDefault VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @xml XML;

INSERT INTO @ValueVM
SELECT 1,'Sample Text','false'

SELECT * FROM @ValueVM for XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS;
```

**Required format**

```
'<?xml version="1.0"?><ValueVM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Id>0</Id><Text>sample</Text><IsDefault>false</IsDefault></ValueVM>'
```

**Current format**

```
'<Id>1</Id><Text>Sample Text</Text><IsDefault>false</IsDefault>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
DECLARE @ValueVM TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Text VARCHAR(MAX),
    IsDefault VARCHAR(10)
)


INSERT INTO @ValueVM
SELECT 1,'Sample Text','false';

DECLARE @FinalXML NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
           +
           CAST((SELECT * FROM @ValueVM AS ValueVM for XML AUTO, ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
);
SELECT @FinalXML;
```

Comment: The format is different, element  has prefix "_x0040_"  <?xml version="1.0"?><_x0040_ValueVM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Id>1</Id><Text>Sample Text</Text><IsDefault>false</IsDefault></_x0040_ValueVM>

Comment: @SreekanthJagaleti, you can try the above modified query to get exact format.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to do that in a simple form. Please try this:

```
DECLARE @ValueVM TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Text VARCHAR(MAX),
    IsDefault VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @xml XML;

INSERT INTO @ValueVM
SELECT 1,'Sample Text','false'


DECLARE @resultXML XML=
(
    SELECT * FROM @ValueVM ValueVM 
    for XML Auto, elements XSINIL
);

DECLARE @resultXMLAndHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
           +
        replace(CAST(@resultXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'instance">', 'instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">')
);
SELECT @resultXMLAndHeader;
```